# SQL return exactly one row or null in a select sub-query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

In Oracle, is it possible to have a sub-query within a select statement that returns a column if exactly one row is returned by the sub-query and null if none or more than one row is returned by the sub-query?

Example:

```
SELECT X,
  Y,
  Z,
  (SELECT W FROM TABLE2 WHERE X = TABLE1.X) /* but return null if 0 or more than 1 rows is returned */
FROM TABLE1;
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can use the case statement.. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about going about it in a different way? A simple LEFT OUTER JOIN with a subquery should do what you want:

```
SELECT T1.X
 ,T1.Y
 ,T1.Z
 ,T2.W
FROM TABLE1 AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT X
      ,W
    FROM TABLE2
    GROUP BY X,W
    HAVING COUNT(X) = 1
) AS T2 ON T2.X = T1.X;
```

This will only return items that have exactly 1 instance of X, and LEFT OUTER JOIN it back to the table when appropriate (leaving the non-matches NULL).

This is also ANSI-compliant, so it is quite performant.

Comment: You haven't selected `X` inside the subquery.

Comment: derp! thank u @ypercube. i also realized no need to group by, since the return will always be exactly 1 per instance.

Comment: Well, sorry but that will not run as it is. You need either aggregation or some window/analytic function wizadry. You can't just `SELECT x, w` with a `HAVING` clause around.

Comment: derp again ... this is what i get for not testing haha. `HAVING` requires a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @PlantTheldea This almost works except I get extra rows instead of the same number of rows as Table1. I tried other types of joins but they all return slightly more or slightly less rows than Table1.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea In the part HAVING COUNT(X), X is the field that joins the two tables together. But in my situation, which I didn't mention above, there are several columns needed to join the two tables. What fields are supposed to go in the COUNT() function?

Comment: @Bumper - in that case you would need to go with a different option, this can easily not work with a larger `JOIN` requirement. please in the future provide a problem that mimics the one you are trying to solve.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea - I ended up using this join method but with a COUNT(DISTINCT W) in the inner select/group by, and without the HAVING statement.

Comment: Great answer. This was exactly what I was looking for. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Besides a `CASE` solution or rewriting the inline subquery as an outer join, this will work, if you can apply an aggregate function (`MIN` or `MAX`) on the `W` column:

```
SELECT X,
  Y,
  Z,
  (SELECT MIN(W) FROM TABLE2 WHERE X = TABLE1.X HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) AS W
FROM TABLE1;
```

Comment: And this does **not** require a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    X, Y, Z, (SELECT W FROM TABLE2 WHERE X = TABLE1.X HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) 
FROM 
    TABLE1;
```

Comment: Doing this requires a group by and when I do the group by I get an error stating "single-row subquery returns more than one row." It's probably worth mentioning that the subquery's where clause has multiple parts. Table 1 and 2 have several fields that are required to match rows, not just W.

Answer (score 0):

my answer is: dont use subselects (unless you are sure ...)

no need and not a good idea to use a subselect here as PlantTheIdea mentioned because of two things

explaination:

subselect means:

one select for each row of the primary select result set. i.e. if you get 1000 rows, you also get 1000 (small) select statemts in your db-system (ignoring optimizer here)

and(!)

with a subselect you have a good chance to hide (or override) a heavy database or select problem. that means: you are only expecting none (NULL) or one (exactly) row (both easily resolvable with a [left outer] join). if there are more than one in your subselect there is something wrong, the SQL Error points that out

the "HAVING COUNT(X) = 1" of course correct, has the small (or not small) problem, thats: "why is there a count of more than one row?"

I spent hours of lifetime finding a workarround like this, just ending up in "dont do it if you are realy sure ..."

I see that in opposite to a "having" like this

```
 ...
 HAVING date=max(date) -- depends on sql dialect
```

or

```
where date = select max(date) from same_table
```

and with my last example i again want to point out: if you get here more than one row (both from today ;.) you have a DB problem - you chould use a timestamp instead for example